# How to create a File (a la Lightning) and link it to a Case via REST API?

Tags: lightning, rest-api, rest, attachment, files

In the Lightning UI if you attach a file to a Case it won't be created as an `Attachment`, rather as a `File`. I could not find anything about this in the REST API docs.

What I found just by try and error is that one must create a `ContentBody`, a `ContentDocument`, a `ContentDocumentVersion` and finally a `ContentDocumentLink` to link it to the Case. If this is really the way, how to upload the file in the first place? i.e. how to create a `ContentBody`? Again nothing related to this in the docs.

My assumption is that still a multi-part request with a `Body` part should work but haven't tried it yet. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these three steps to create a File and link it to your object.

### Create a `ContentVersion`

Follow the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_contentversion) to create a new version with a multipart request. Note that this will automatically create a `ContentDocument` but unfortunately does not return its id. What it returns is the `id` of the created `ContentVersion` which we call `$CONTENT_VERSION_ID`

### Fetch `id` of the automatically created `ContentDocument`

Run the following SOQL query:

`SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = '$CONTENT_VERSION_ID'`

It will return an id which we call `$CONTENT_DOCUMENT_ID`

### Link `ContentDocument` to Object

Create a `ContentDocumentLink` object using the following `json`:

`POST /sobjects/ContentDocumentLink`

`{
  ContentDocumentId: $CONTENT_DOCUMENT_ID,
  LinkedEntityId: $SOBJECT_ID,
  ShareType: "V"
}`